# How to determine discrete categories?

Tags: categorical-data

I don't know if this is specific enough, but if it isn't, I wouldn't mind you guys asking questions to clarify. So here it goes.

1. I have a data set containing a finite number of points $X$.
2. I'm 100% sure that these points belong to discrete, non-overlapping categories.
3. However, I don't know what these categories are.
4. But what I **do** have, for each datapoint, is a meaningful collection of continuous traits (that is, each point in X is an element of $(0, 1)^n$).

Is there a way to, using these continuous traits, to determine **what are the most likely groupings** of the datapoints in X?

Comment: Do you know *how many* categories you have?

Comment: What exactly is the structure of $X$?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use a technique called [Clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis). This is an *unsupervised* technique -- you don't have example answers (i.e. what the groupings are) -- so be prepared to explore around and to have to make judgements.

Comment: What do I do if I don't know $k$? (And I don't)

Comment: @TomislavOstojich Unsupervised learning is a bit of reading the tea leaves. One thing people do is to run for multiple $k$ and pick the $k$ that minimizes a statistic. Or you can use something like dbscan, where you specify a distance (within which it will jump from one data point to another, extending a cluster). You'll need to educate yourself a bit.

Comment: What's a good statistic to minimize?

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many categories there are, go for a k-means clustering algorythm!

If you don't know how many there are, there are many techniques, but you still have a clustering probloem anyway!